# Python XML hierarchy formating when creating new subelements

Tags: xml, python-3.x, format, editing

i have a problem that when i update an XML file after creating a sub-element the file does not update with a hierarchy format and it does not keep the `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import time
tree = ET.parse('TEST.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

x=root
newuser=ET.SubElement(x,("USER name='admin2' "))
tree.write("TEST.xml")
```

here is my XML file before i run the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
</root>
```

and here is the XML file after i run the code:

```
<root>
<USER name='admin2'  /></root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty printing in XML is something of a dark art... how do you know whether a given text node is part of the document or just there for decoration? LXML tends to be conservative when making these decisions. If the document has text nodes, even ones with just "\n", it may not pretty print the document. But you can strip the nodes yourself after loading:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as etree
>>> root = etree.fromstring("""<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<root>\n</root>""")
>>> root.text
'\n'
>>> for elem in root.iter("*"):
...     if elem.text:
...         elem.text = elem.text.strip() or None
... 
>>>
```

Now you can add your data

```
>>> etree.SubElement(root, "USER", name="admin2")
<Element USER at 0x7fd60d37efc8>
```

Then, when you serialize the document, you can add an xml declaration and choose to pretty print the output.

```
>>> serialized=etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
>>> print(serialized.decode("ascii"))
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<root>
  <USER name="admin2"/>
</root>
```

Comment: NameError 'etree' is not defined?

Comment: My bad! I had lxml on my brain and did `import lxml.etree as etree`. I don't think ElementTree does pretty printing. So, maybe the answer is to switch to lxml.